# issue on upgrading dev express v12 to v13.1 - Type 'GridViewEditItemTemplateContainer' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, upgrade

I have a project that has no problem while compiling in VS 2010 with dev express v12.1

I would like to upgrade the same project in VS 2010 with DX13.1.I have installed dev express 13.1 version
, used the Project Converter in DX13.1 and looked like it upgraded
without issues and also changed the compile setting of the project to .NET 4.0 , reference all DevExpress.Web.*.I also checked the referenced dll and do not find DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v13.1 and also clear bin and object folder.

After running the project i got the below issue.

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type
>   'GridViewEditItemTemplateContainer' is not defined.

Source Error:

```
Line 7:  
Line 8:      Public Sub InstantiateIn(pContainer As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn
Line 9:          Dim TemplateContainer As GridViewEditItemTemplateContainer
```

Can you please suggest me what i am missing?

Thanks
kailash

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView namespace is imported:

**VB.NET**

```
Import DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView
```

**C#:**

```
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;
```

You can right click to the problematic type and choose the "Resolve" command to automatically resolved such issues.